# asp.net webapi validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an API Controller and call action from JS:

```
$('#create-se').on('click', function () {
    var data = {};

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/registration',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function () {
        }
    });
});

public bool Post(UserRegistrationViewModel model)
{           
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Model has few required properties and few StringLength. When I send data from js to controller ModelState.IsValid always returns true. I can't figure out how to solve it. Even if posted model is null, Model.IsValid is true anyway

Comment: How does your `UserRegistrationViewModel` model look like?

Answer (score 0):

http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/
This website has a better way of doing validation and using headers to send the token across and if it invalid it will return validation failed.

Comment: For testing it they have sample programs attached on there website

Comment: I just used there config.Filters.Add(new TokenValidationAttribute());

Comment: to do token validation then on the header you add : Authorization-Token: #number assigned. To get the number you have to encode the username you want and then have a username class that checks to see if that username is in the username base but only after decoding it